# $X \sim U(0, 2)$, $Y \sim U(0, 3)$ independently: $P(Y \le X^2)$

Tags: statistics, integration

Suppose $X \sim U(0,2)$ and $Y \sim U(0,3)$ independently.

Then $0 < X <2$ and $0 < Y < 3$.

Evaluate $P(Y \leq X^2)$.

By integrating over the region, I get $P = \dfrac{4}{9}$, but the solutions indicate that I should be getting $P = 0.4226$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you did the integration over the wrong region. Here is what I did:

\begin{align*}
\Pr(Y\le X^2) &= \int_{0}^{3} \left(\int _{\sqrt{y}}^2\frac{1}{2\cdot3}\text{d}x \right)\text{d}y\\
& = \frac{1}{6} \left(6-2 \sqrt{3}\right)\\&\approx 0.42265
\end{align*}